# Internet Explorer do not open php-file (can not find)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, internet-explorer, authentication

I have a simple login formular on my website to login to the next site using ajax:

```
    <form id="formlogin" method="post" action="login.php" role="login">
        <img src="img/logologin.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="user" type="username" name="username" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter username" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login Now</button>
    </form>
```

this is my ajax code:

```
$("#formlogin").submit(function() {
    user = $("#user").val();
    sessionID = $("#user").val() + getDateTime();
    time = getTime();
    logindate = getDate();
    timeStamp = getTimeStamp();

    sessionData.sessionID = sessionID;
    sessionData.loginTime = time;
    sessionData.loginDate = logindate;
    sessionData.user = user;
    sessionData.timeStamp = timeStamp;

    var sessionIDJSON = JSON.stringify(sessionData);
    Cookies.set('user', sessionData, {expires: 3, path: 'Main.html'});
});
```

It used to work before I didnt use bootstrap, but I am pretty sure, that it is not the reason.

Other Browsers (chrome,firefox) work fine except IE.
Internet Explorer tells me that there is an error of opening the login.php file. Right after logging in it seems like it is going to login, but jumps back. And the webdevtool tells me the error.

Maybe someone had the same experience with it. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you check if IE's actually hitting your server? what exactly is in this php file?

Comment: my MySql connection. what do you mean by hitting?